# Extended Statistics with WEKA

Tags: java, weka

I am using WEKA programmatically.
Is there an easy way to get the same statistic as provided by the WEKA-Gui? (Class-distribution etc.) or have one to generate it by hand (using jfree or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Evaluation class to validate your classifier. Just check this link
[Weka Evaluation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html)

For example you have this Method:

> ```
> toClassDetailsString()
> ```
>
> Generates a breakdown of the accuracy for each class (with default title), incorporating various information-retrieval statistics, such as true/false positive rate, precision/recall/F-Measure.

Also you can get everythink e.g. Area under ROC, Accuracy or NumFalsePositives as double values.

Comment: Thank yo.. but i meant statistics about the dataset.. like a plot of the distribution of the numeric attributes as provided be weka-explorer.. its not a problem to generate it by hand.. but I wonder where these graphics are coming from (I might miss a "plotting-API")

Comment: Okay, thats a little bit difficult to see from your question. I'm not aware about plotting or statistic generating functions of instances in weka.